# Tabulator: Freeze header of multiple tabulator in same page without fixing height

Tags: jquery, css, tabulator

My web page having more then 3 tabulator and also few charts in between tables.

As per the requirement we are not fixing size of table. So based on data the table height varies.

I want to fix header of the tables in UI. So that at the of vertical scroll the header will remain fixed and only data get scrolled.

```js
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
];

//initialize table
var table = new Tabulator("#tblData1", {
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    autoColumns:false, //create columns from data field names
    printAsHtml:true,
    columns:[                 //define the table columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", width:"15%"},
        <!-- {title:"Task Progress", field:"progress", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress", editor:true}, -->
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender", width:95, editor:"select", editorParams:{values:["male", "female"]}, width:"15%"},
        <!-- {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", hozAlign:"center", width:100, editor:true}, -->
        {title:"Color", field:"col",headerFilter:true, width:130, editor:"input", width:"15%"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", width:130, sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center", width:"15%"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", width:90,  hozAlign:"center", formatter:"tickCross", sorter:"boolean", editor:true, width:"16%"},
        {title:"Test",width:"24%",
        columns:[
        {title:"Test1",width:"12%"},
        {title:"Test2",width:"12%"},
        ]},
    ],
});

var table = new Tabulator("#tblData2", {
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    autoColumns:false, //create columns from data field names
    printAsHtml:true,
    columns:[                 //define the table columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", width:"15%"},
        <!-- {title:"Task Progress", field:"progress", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress", editor:true}, -->
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender", width:95, editor:"select", editorParams:{values:["male", "female"]}, width:"15%"},
        <!-- {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", hozAlign:"center", width:100, editor:true}, -->
        {title:"Color", field:"col",headerFilter:true, width:130, editor:"input", width:"15%"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", width:130, sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center", width:"15%"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", width:90,  hozAlign:"center", formatter:"tickCross", sorter:"boolean", editor:true, width:"16%"},
        {title:"Test",width:"24%",
        columns:[
        {title:"Test1",width:"12%"},
        {title:"Test2",width:"12%"},
        ]},
    ],
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tblData1" style="width:550px;"></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="tblData2" style="width:550px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Similar example: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that then you will have to specify a max height on the table otherwise it wont know when to show a scroll bar.

Without either a `height` or a `maxHeight` set the table will assume you want to show all data in the table at which point the table will take up its maximum height and therefore any scroll will happen on its parent element or the page body at which point the header will scroll with the table.

`height` or `maHeight` can be set in any valid CSS height value.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    maxHeight:"100%", //do not let table get bigger than the height of its parent element
});
```

More information on this can be found in the [Layout Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/layout#height-variable)